# use of google script editor

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Hey so currently working on my first personal project so bear with the questions!

Currently trying to create a Javascript program that will parse info from google forms to produce slides displaying the info. So far from my research the best way I've found to facilitate this process is googles app script editor. However, I was wondering if I can run this code by requesting it from a different javascript (or maybe even java) program that I will write code on webstorm. If I cant do this what is the best way to utilize the google apps script editor? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Google Apps Script is just javascript with extra built-in APIs (like [`SpreadsheetApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app), [`FormApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app), etc.).

It also has a [`UrlFetchApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) API.

So you can run code like this:

```
// The code below logs the HTML code of the Google home page.
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.google.com/");
Logger.log(response.getContentText());
```

As such, if you want to provide JavaScript from elsewhere, you could fetch it and then `eval` it on the Google Apps Script side. (but we all know [how tricky `eval` can get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea))

One other option is to have your own server side written using [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/) (or any other framework) and use [Google's OAuth](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2-code-flow) and authorize your app to fetch data from the `Forms` form

Answer (score 0):

## Slides and Google Apps Script

You might like to take a look at the addon "Slides Merge" by Bruce McPherson.  I've never used it but it sounds like it might work for you.  Here's what it's looks like in the addon store:
[image]

> Getting information from Google Forms is a snap with google apps script since your can link the form right up to a spreadsheet. The Google Apps Script documentation is really quite good these days. Here's the [documentation link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet).  Google Apps Script is loosely based on [Javascript 1.6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.6).  If your already a programmer my guess is that you'll have few problems learning to use it.  In my experience the most difficult thing was dealing with the arrays of arrays produced by the getValues() method of ranges in google apps script and I made a [short video](https://sites.google.com/view/googlappsscript/javascript-array-difficulties) that might be of some help to you.

I also have a script that I wrote in Google Apps Script that produces a [sheet show](https://sites.google.com/view/googlappsscript/sheetshow) that is a slide show inside of a spreadsheet.

I've found that using the Script Editor is pretty easy.  There's some documentation in the [support section](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support) of the documentation.  It can be a bit buggy at times but overall I think it's a pretty good tool.